# Failed to get D-Bus connection - httpd service in Docker container

Tags: apache, centos, docker, dbus

I am creating a Dockerfile for PostgreSQL with CentOS7 as the base image. I am trying to start httpd service with the following command in the container,

```
service httpd start
```

and i get the following error:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  httpd.service
Failed to get D-Bus connection: No connection to service manager.
```

The log file directory /var/log/httpd is also empty. I guess this is the problem with Docker CentOS7 image. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this a well.
It might not be the best way, but you can find a copy of the `/etc/init.d/httpd` file from another computer. copy that into the container in /etc/init.d
then run
`chkconfig --level 345 httpd on`

then you will be able to use either 
`/etc/init.d/httpd start` or `service httpd start`